# A suitable tag question

Tags: tag-questions

What is the most suitable tag question used after the following sentence?

Everybody forgot to congratulate her, ...........?

By the way, l have found several different answers, such as "did they", "don't you think" , "isn't that so" and " didn' they". But l am not really sure of the most suitable one.

Comment: Everybody forgot to congratulate her, _didn't they_?

Answer (score 2):

Tag questions (short answer) in declarative sentences:

**A tag is formed by taking the helping verb of the main verb (make it a question to find the helping verb)**.

**Everybody forgot to congratulate her**.

**Did** everybody forget to congratulate her?

TAG: Everybody forgot to congratulate her, **didn't they**?

Main verb: forget Tense: simple past (forgot).

Also, don't forget that in a declarative sentence tag, the tag must be negative interrogative (didn't they?). In a negative sentence, the tag must be plain interrogative (They didn't forget  to congratulate her, did they?).

You can practice with these:
The boys have found the dog and brought him home. [tricky, kind of]
You will be going to school this afternoon.
We wouldn't have been in town so late, normally.

Clues: the helping verbs are either in the sentence (have, will, is/are, would/should) but in the present and simple past, you have to come up with [do/does and did).

You speak Russian, don't you? You have to remember that do is the helping verb.

This is just a basic introduction, not the whole entire story.

Here is an important irregularity:
I'm being clear, aren't I? :) [regular]
VERSUS I'm being clear, am I? [in response to  praise or to be sarcastic, for example]

That one does not follow the rules, you just have to learn it. First person sentence in the present tense with a tag.

Also, in a negative sentence: I'm not being clear, am I?

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of tag questions :
1. Opposite polarity tag questions

> She’s a translator, isn’t she?
>    (affirmative main clause + negative tag)
>
> He hasn’t arrived yet, has he? (negative main clause + affirmative tag)

We can use type 1 question tags when we expect the answer to the question to confirm that what we say in the main clause is true:

The second type of question is similar polarity tag questions  which consist  of an affirmative main clause and an affirmative tag:

> You’re Joe’s cousin, are you?

We can use type 2 tags when we do not know if the answer is yes or no. The intonation is usually a rising tone.

We can use right and yeah in very informal situations instead of question tags:

> So, you’re not coming with us tonight, right?

"Everybody" requires "they", you can say "didn't they", "did they", "right/yeah", "you know" in different situations.